# ASP.NET RootPath property @Url.Content("~/") in Javascript Revealing Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to consolidate all my javascript ajax calls into a Javascript Revealing Module.
However there is 1 global javascript property called RootPath which is hard coded into the View page with an inpage script tag using:

```
var RootPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

In a separate .js file I am creating calls to fetch JSON from my server side.

```
    var dataService = function () {
        var url = RootPath + "API/GetData",
        getData = function () {
            return $.getJSON(url);
        };

        return {
            getData: getData
        };
}();
```

Issue is that inside the Javascript object this global RootPath is undefined.  How can I get this global property inside my object?

Comment: I usually put the url in a hidden field on the form and pull that hidden field from the javascript

Comment: Can you please confirm that seperate js get included after the onpage script which define the "RootPath" Variable?

Comment: If you really want to use that "global" RootPath variable, one thing you could do is this, window.rootPath = '@Url.Content("~/")'; (this should be in the layout page or in a place you know it runs first than the javascript file) and then on your javascript file just do, window.rootPath

Comment: put inside _layout.cshtml and use everywhere .. js , html , cshtml..

Comment: If I use window.rootPath = instead of just RootPath = in my master template _layout.cshtml...can I use the RootPath variable the same way in other javascripts.  The issue is there are other developers who are using this variable.  So I don't want to affect their code, it is just that they don't use the js revealing module.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method in the past to good effect:

```
<base href="@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))">
```

You shouldn't need to specify it per request then.

Definition of the base tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: I will have to look into this

Comment: example is for images, this is a script...that news up an object before anything else runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the global variable in the top of the page/layout.cs html;

```
<html><head>
</script type="text/javascript">
var RootPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
<script src="my_jsfiles" type="text/javascript">

<head>
```

Defining the js at the top level will be always accessible from all the places of the page

Comment: This is what I am doing, the RootPath variable is accessible in my separate .js file.  However when the js revealing module class is newed up it has RootPath as undefined.  I look in the WatchList and it isn't there.  When the function is called it is defined, so I can call it inside my function, but cannot specify it as a variable in my js object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use that "global" RootPath variable, one thing you could do is this,

`window.rootPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';`

(this should be in the layout page or in a place you know it runs first than the javascript file) and then on your javascript file just do,

```
var dataService = function () {
        var url = window.rootPath + "API/GetData",
        getData = function () {
            return $.getJSON(url);
        };

        return {
            getData: getData
        };
```

Comment: do I need to put var in front of it?                                                                                     t       var window.rootPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';                      because just typing what you did in _layout.cshtml the variable is still not there when I new up my revealing module.

Comment: no you don't need var, window is the browser, you always have access to window in javascript or browser console.

Answer (score -1):

can you please try this ??

```
    var dataService = function () {
        var url = "/API/GetData",
        getData = function () {
            return $.getJSON(url);
        };

        return {
            getData: getData
        };
}();
```

Please note i have removed `RootPath`  variable and directly used `var url = "/API/GetData"` .. just try this i think it should work

Comment: what if he has url something like localhost/webapp... in this case your call goes to localhost/api/getdata ... it never work..

Comment: this does work, but the app is deployed in separate instances on the website on subfolders ie.  http://xxx.com/abc and http://xxx.com/xyz  so the RootPath is there to change the URL of the AJAX calls